# Tensorflow 2.0 - Layer with fixed input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use Tensorflow to optimize a few variables to be used in a KNN algorithm, however, I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to have a layer work properly if it is not connected to an `Input` layer.

What I'm trying to do below is pass in `[[1]]` as a static tensor, and then using the `Lambda` layer to coerce the weights into a usable shape.  Once trained, I would just retrieve the weight value from the first `Dense` layer.

```
ones = tf.ones(shape=(1,1)) # trying to use this to take the place of dynamic inputs

theta_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear", use_bias=False, trainable=True)(ones)
theta_layer = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.ones(shape=(self.batch_size,1)) * x)(theta_layer)
print(theta_layer)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[-1.151663]
# [-1.151663]
# [-1.151663]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)

concat_layer = layers.Concatenate()([theta_layer, features_input])

model = models.Model(inputs=features_input, outputs=concat_layer)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse") #, metrics=["mae"])#, bias_regularizer=None)
```

The problem with the above strategy is that `theta_layer` does not show up in `model.summary()` and the weights don't show up in `model.get_weights()`.

Also, when I try to directly set `theta_layer` as the model output, I get this message:

```
AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.
```

This is probably the giveaway but frankly I'm just not knowledgeable enough about Tensorflow.

I know that I can fix this by passing in a separate `tf.ones` input to the model (not just into specific layers), but it would complicate the code seemingly unnecessarily (I have to do this for multiple layers/variables).  Is there a way that I can alter the `tf.ones` passed to the layer or the alter the layer itself to eliminate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like a bit of a hack, but I was able to infer something from an answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46466275/6182971

It works if I change the first line above from:

```
ones = tf.ones(shape=(1,1))
```

to:

```
ones = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.ones(shape=(1,1)))(features_input)
```

Even though the `Lambda` layer is returning a constant, passing in `features_input`, which is the main training data connects the `tf.ones` constant to the network inputs, which seems to be sufficient.